# Convert triplets to matrix/dataframe in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am using csr matrix in scipy. When I am printing the matrix, the output is like:

```
(669974, 73)  0.005
(669974, 74)  0.007
(669974, 75)  0.002
(669974, 76)  0.006
(669974, 77)  0.005
```

I want to convert it to matrix/dataframe in the form of triplets only. Like:

```
col1     col2      val
669974    73      0.005
669974    74      0.007
669974    75      0.002
669974    76      0.006
669974    77      0.005
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample sparse matrix:

```
In [363]: A=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))
```

show it as a dense (regular numpy) array (e.g. `A.toarray()`)

```
In [364]: A.A
Out[364]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]], dtype=int32)
```

Its `repr` display

```
In [365]: A
Out[365]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Its `str()` display (what you saw)

```
In [366]: print(A)
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 2)    2
  (0, 3)    3
  (1, 0)    4
  (1, 1)    5
  (1, 2)    6
  (1, 3)    7
  (2, 0)    8
  (2, 1)    9
  (2, 2)    10
  (2, 3)    11
```

`A.data` is its data attribute, the values.  You can get the coordinates with `nonzero`:

```
In [368]: A.nonzero()
Out[368]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

Or convert `csr` to `coo` format, and get all 3 arrays:

```
In [369]: Ac=A.tocoo()
In [370]: Ac.data
Out[370]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32)
In [371]: Ac.row
Out[371]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
In [372]: Ac.col
Out[372]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

You could turn them into a 3 column array with:

```
In [373]: np.column_stack((Ac.col, Ac.row, Ac.data))
Out[373]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  0,  2],
       [ 3,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  5],
       [ 2,  1,  6],
       [ 3,  1,  7],
       [ 0,  2,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  9],
       [ 2,  2, 10],
       [ 3,  2, 11]], dtype=int32)
```

Except if your data is float, then this becomes all floats.  It can't mix ints and floats.

You can assemble them into a structured array with 2 int fields and one float one.  I can elaborate on that if needed.

But your mention of dataframe suggests you are familiar with `pandas` - if so you probably can take it from here.